# R: adding and modifying observations if it meets certain conditions

Tags: r, copy, dataframe, rows

I have a data frame like this:

```
nation      post   frequency count

Australia    0         4     2 
Australia    1         7     2 
Brazil       0         1     1 
Finland      1         1     1
```

what I like is to add observations if count == 1, and the observation to be add need to meet the condition:

1. if post = 0, then added observation have post value = 1
2. if post = 1, then added observation have post value = 0
3. all added observations have frequency = 0
4. after adding observations, change count to 2 for "old" and "new" obs.

so the output should be something like:

```
nation      post   frequency count

Australia    0         4     2 
Australia    1         7     2 
Brazil       0         1     2
Brazil       1         0     2 
Finland      1         1     2
Finland      0         0     2
```

It seems rather complicated to program as a R novice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better methods, but here's a go with a pretty intuitive step-by-step `if` statement.

```
Reduce(rbind, Map(function(x) {
    if(nrow(x) == 1L) {
        rb <- rbind(x, x)    ## add a duplicate row
        rb[2,2] <- !rb[1,2]  ## change post to "opposite" of its original value
        rb[2,3] <- 0L        ## change frequency to zero
        rb$count <- 2L       ## change count to 2
        rb
    } else {
        x
    }
}, split(df, df$nation)))
#       nation post frequency count
# 1  Australia    0         4     2
# 2  Australia    1         7     2
# 3     Brazil    0         1     2
# 21    Brazil    1         0     2
# 4    Finland    1         1     2
# 22   Finland    0         0     2
```